# Variance components of tensor interactions in R::mgcv

Tags: r, interaction, gam, mgcv

Why does the `mgcv::gam.vcomp` show two variance components for interactions made with `mgcv::ti`?¨

I can't seem to find the explanation or the between-the-lines explanation anywhere. Is is perhaps variance attributed to each components in the interaction?

```
require(mgcv)
test1 <- function(x,z,sx=0.3,sz=0.4) { 
  x <- x*20
  (pi**sx*sz)*(1.2*exp(-(x-0.2)^2/sx^2-(z-0.3)^2/sz^2)+
                 0.8*exp(-(x-0.7)^2/sx^2-(z-0.8)^2/sz^2))
}
n <- 500
old.par <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
x <- runif(n)/20;z <- runif(n);
xs <- seq(0,1,length=30)/20;zs <- seq(0,1,length=30)
pr <- data.frame(x=rep(xs,30),z=rep(zs,rep(30,30)))
truth <- matrix(test1(pr$x,pr$z),30,30)
f <- test1(x,z)
y <- f + rnorm(n)*0.2
b3 <- gam(y~ ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(x,z))
b3s <- gam(y~ ti(x) + ti(z) + s(x,z)) # describing the itneraction with s().
```

I know we're sort of mixing apples and oranges here.

```
gam.vcomp(b3)
     ti(x)      ti(z)   ti(x,z)1   ti(x,z)2 
0.06609731 0.01476070 0.08834218 0.05700322 

gam.vcomp(b3s)
    ti(x)     ti(z)    s(x,z) 
0.1623056 2.4870344 7.7484987
```

Comment: `?mgcv::gam.vcomp` says "Note that variance components are also returned for tensor product smooths, but that their interpretation is not so straightforward." ... I don't know if the references therein, or Wood's book, will help ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was hoping someone had managed to elucidate anything more. I couldn't find  anything in those references. Perhaps its elaborated in the 2nd edition of his book.

Comment: the only other suggestion I have is to start digging into the code; that would at least tell you what computations were being done, although it might not help with the interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see the same behaviour with `te(x, z)`

```
> b <- gam(y ~ te(x,z))
> gam.vcomp(b)
  te(x,z)1   te(x,z)2 
0.08668107 0.04596708
```

and arises because tensor product smooths are defined by two, in this case, marginal bases, each of which have a smoothness parameter. Hence there are two variance components, one per smoothness parameter/marginal basis.

1. `ti(x,z)1` is the variance component for the marginal basis of `x`,
2. `ti(x,z)2` is the variance component for the marginal basis of `z`.

As these tensor product interactions smooth have had the main effects removed from them, physical interpretation is complicated, but in a practical sense, the values are the variance component interpretation of the smoothness parameters of the marginal bases.

The reason `s(x, z)` has just one variance component is that it is a 2-d thinplate spline basis. This basis is isotropic; there is the same smoothness in the to dimensions and hence a single smoothness parameter is required for the basis. Hence there is a single variance component.

Comment: I suspected something like that. Thanks! But as @Ben Bolker commented, is there any new references as to the "straightforwardness" of their interpretation?

Comment: Not really; the 2nd edition of Simon's book is the definitive account regarding mgcv. I wonder if the comment about the "interpretation" of variance components of tensor product smooths relates to the fact that there isn't a single variance component with which to compare with other terms in the model if you are doing a variance decomposition.

There may be more detail in papers or other text that specifically discuss the mixed model formulation of the GAM?